Line between aligned equations
When I do calculations by hand, I like to align my equations and connect their equal signs with a vertical line. I'm trying to replicate this in LaTeX. My idea is to use the array environment to do the alignment and add the vertical line. Here is a MWE of what I did so far.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Make an equal sign with a white background
\newcommand\weq{
    \hskip-7pt%
    \raise-3pt\hbox{\tcbox[
        colback=white, colframe=white, boxrule=0mm, 
        left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, sharp corners
    ]{$=$}}%
    \hskip3pt%
}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{15pt}

% Define the environment
\newenvironment{myarray}{
    \begin{array}{r@{\hskip8pt}@{\vline}>{\displaystyle}l}
}{
    \end{array}
}

% Usage
\begin{document}
$$
\begin{myarray}
V(x) 
&\weq \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Big( 5(x + 2)^2 + 3x + 1 \Big) \\
&\quad\hbox{Apply derivation rules} \\
&\weq 10(x + 2) + 3 \\
&\weq 10x + 23 \\
&\weq \int_0^x 10 \; dx + 23 \\
\end{myarray}
$$
\end{document}


The problem with this implementation is that the vertical line proceeds above the first equal sign and below the last one, but I don't want that. The same problem happens if I use a | separator instead of placing \vlines. How can I fix this problem without changing the "Usage" part of the MWE?

You could define two more commands, which leave out the upper and lower line respectively. Think in analogy of opening and closing braces.

It would be nice to have a package that does exactly this.

Unrelated, you should avoid $$ for math equation.

Like this:

With drawing lines between = signs by use of the tikzmark of tikz:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{
    is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt},
        }

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
V(x)    
    & \tikzmarknode[is]{A}{=} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Big( 5(x + 2)^2 + 3x + 1 \Big) \\
&\quad\hbox{Apply derivation rules} \\
    & \tikzmarknode[is]{B}{=} 10(x + 2) + 3 \\
    & \tikzmarknode[is]{C}{=} 10x + 23 \\
    & \tikzmarknode[is]{D}{=} \int_0^x 10 \; dx + 23 \\
    \end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Edit:    For a wee bit shorter code you can define new command for writing \tikzmarknode. For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tmn}{mm}{\tikzmarknode[inner ysep=2pt]{#1}{#2}} % <---

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
V(x)
    & \tmn{A}{=} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Big( 5(x + 2)^2 + 3x + 1 \Big) \\[1ex]
    &\quad\hbox{Apply derivation rules} \\[1ex]
    & \tmn{B}{=} 10(x + 2) + 3 \\
    & \tmn{C}{=} 10x + 23 \\
    & \tmn{D}{=} \int_0^x 10 \; dx + 23 \\
    \end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result is the same as is in the first example.

To get showed result in answer at least two compilations of MWE are needed,

I know I probably won't receive a better answer then this one but I have to comment that this approach, very visually pleasing, actually changes the "Usage" part; it's quite easy to do the equal signs labeling automatically tough. I'm also not very happy about using tikz as this will make documents significantly slower to build. Thanks

Here's a limited sketch of the idea in my comment.
\beq tries overwriting the upper \vline fro the array, like using a white liquid on a type writer. By intention I left an upper portion. For the end \eeq it doesn't work, yet.
However, I think you should use a different approach: one path could be to replace \tcbox with plain Tikz, and using the remember feature to draw a line from node to node later; you may need to use layers then. (@Zarko was faster :)
Also I didn't refactor to generalize the solution more.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Make an equal sign with a white background
\newcommand\weq{%
    \hskip-7pt%
    \raise-3pt\hbox{\tcbox[%
        colback=white, colframe=white, boxrule=0mm,% 
        left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, sharp corners%
    ]{$=$}}%
    \hskip3pt%
}
\newcommand\beq{% begin it
    \hskip-7pt%
    \raise-3pt\hbox{\tcbox[%
        colback=white, colframe=white, boxrule=0mm,% 
        left=0mm, right=0mm, top=14pt, bottom=0mm, sharp corners%
    ]{$=$}}%
    \hskip3pt%
}
\newcommand\eeq{% end it
    \hskip-7pt%
    \raise-3pt\hbox{\tcbox[%
        colback=white, colframe=white, boxrule=0mm,% 
        left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, sharp corners%
    ]{$=$}}%
    \hskip3pt%
}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{15pt}

% Define the environment
\newenvironment{myarray}{
    \begin{array}{r@{\hskip8pt}@{\vline}>{\displaystyle}l}
}{
    \end{array}
}

% Usage
\begin{document}
$$
\begin{myarray}
V(x) 
&\beq \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Big( 5(x + 2)^2 + 3x + 1 \Big) \\
&\quad\hbox{Apply derivation rules} \\
&\weq 10(x + 2) + 3 \\
&\weq 10x + 23 \\
&\eeq \int_0^x 10 \; dx + 23 \\
\end{myarray}
$$
\end{document}


Thanks, but different equations will require manual adjustment to hide the top and bottom lines completely, which is not ideal.
